# Word wrap in DataTables

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have this cell content:

```
<td style="max-width:200px;" class="sorting_1">
<i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i>
<span style="width: 200px;">
    Публикация: "The Myth of Ponce de León and the Fountain of Youth"                                    
</span>

<div class="mt-1">
    <span class="text-small text-muted">
        ID: 23843933046690590                                        
    </span>
</div>
</td>
```

But span does not get 200px width and expands to 400+ px - http://joxi.ru/823BXGpH9ZdEMm

What should I do to limit width to 200px and wrap words in this cell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: block` or `display: inline-block`

```css
.maxWidth {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<td style="max-width:200px;" class="sorting_1">
<i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i>
<span class="maxWidth">
    Публикация: "The Myth of Ponce de León and the Fountain of Youth"                                    
</span>

<div class="mt-1">
    <span class="text-small text-muted">
        ID: 23843933046690590                                        
    </span>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to trim whitespace from the strings you put in your spans, using either JS or C#.

In JS :

```js
myString = myString.trim();
```

In C# :

```cs
myString = myString.Trim();
```

If that's not fixing it, try putting the content within the `<span></span>` in one line, like so :

```html
<span class="text-small text-muted">ID: 23843933046690590</span>
```

Since span has its content as a inline by default, whitespace will count towards the length of the content.